# Visual Studio giving me issues with XAML designer

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I still can't get my setup working properly. It was working and now all of the sudden it doesnt. Yes, I uninstalled Silverlight 5 RC and installed Silverlight 5 if that matters..

Silverlight 4 + PRISM solution
I have "infrastructure" project with my custom controls. I have `generic.xaml` with styles for those controls. I **know** issue is with my custom controls because when I comment it off - it works. Sometime I open view and I see it, but my custom control shows as rectangle.

When I try to drop my control on view by dragging from toolbar:

```
Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(IntPtr ptr, String name, CValue[] cvData)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodPack(IntPtr objectPtr, String methodName, Object[] rawData)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Collection_Add[T](PresentationFrameworkCollection`1 collection, Object value)
   at System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection`1.AddImpl(Object value)
   at System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection`1.System.Collections.IList.Add(Object value)
   at Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.InstantiateChildren(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode, DocumentCompositeNode compositeNode, Boolean isNewInstance)
```

When it fails in view(edit xaml, etc) - I get this:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
Type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' is not marked as serializable.
   at MS.Internal.Designer.VSDesignerClient.RestoreSelection(List`1 offsetsInXamlFile)
   at MS.Internal.Designer.DesignerPane.LoadDesignerView(Boolean isReload)
```

Everything works great at runtime and it works great in Blend (I solved Blend issue with this: [ExpressionBlend exception when UserControl contains my custom control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159123/expressionblend-exception-when-usercontrol-contains-my-custom-control) and this: [How to properly organize XAML resources in Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184264/how-to-properly-organize-xaml-resources-in-silverlight))

I wasted ton's of time on this already.. It also works fine in VS in my test project where I don't have much - just test view and reference to infrastructure. I wish there was a way to somehow debug Visual Studio..

**EDIT**
Debugging VS. Getting this first:

```
at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Platform.SilverlightViewProducer.OnUnhandledException(Object sender, ViewUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Platform.SilverlightViewProducer.OnViewUpdated()
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Platform.ViewProducerBase.<get_DesignModeValueProviderService>b__7(IInstanceBuilderContext invokingContext)
   at MS.Internal.Services.DesignModeValueProviderService.ValueTranslationServicePropertyInvalidated(Object sender, PropertyInvalidatedEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.Features.DesignModeValueProviderConnector.ValueTranslationServiceImpl.InvalidateProperty(ModelItem item, PropertyIdentifier property)
   at MS.Internal.FrameworkElementControl.FrameworkElementDesignTimePropertiesAdorner.SetDesignResizeMode(Boolean updateView)
   at MS.Internal.FrameworkElementControl.FrameworkElementDesignTimePropertiesAdorner..ctor(ModelItem item)
   at MS.Internal.FrameworkElementControl.FrameworkElementDesignTimePropertiesGrabHandleAdornerProvider.Activate(ModelItem item)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Interaction.AdornerProvider.InvokeActivate(EditingContext context, ModelItem item)
   at MS.Internal.Features.AdornerProviderFeatureConnector.FeatureProvidersAdded(ModelItem item, IEnumerable`1 extensions)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Policies.PolicyDrivenFeatureConnector`1.OnPolicyItemsChanged(Object sender, PolicyItemsChangedEventArgs e)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.Policies.ItemPolicy.OnPolicyItemsChanged(PolicyItemsChangedEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.Policies.SoleSelectionPolicy.RaisePolicyItemsChanged(ModelItem oldSoleSelection, ModelItem newSoleSelection)
   at MS.Internal.Policies.SoleSelectionPolicy.OnSelectionChanged(Selection newSelection)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.ContextItemManager.SubscribeProxy`1.SubscribeContext(ContextItem item)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.SubscribeContextCallback.Invoke(ContextItem item)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.EditingContext.DefaultContextItemManager.OnItemChanged(ContextItem item)
   at Microsoft.Windows.Design.EditingContext.DefaultContextItemManager.SetValue(ContextItem value)
   at MS.Internal.Designer.VSDesigner.VSDesignerClientImpl.RestoreSelection(List`1 selectionOffsetsInXamlFile)
```

With inner exceptions:

> {"[Parser_SetValue_Exception]\r\nArguments:
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.Style\r\nDebugging resource strings
>   are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient
>   information to diagnose the problem. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=4.0.60831.0&File=System.Windows.dll&Key=Parser_SetValue_Exception
>   [Line: 0 Position: 0]"}

```
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CreateFromXaml(UnmanagedMemoryStream stream, String sourceAssemblyName, Boolean createNamescope, Boolean requireDefaultNamespace, Boolean allowEventHandlers)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.GetBuiltInStyle(IntPtr nativeTarget, IntPtr& nativeStyle)
```

Comment: if you have blend then open it up in blend. Also, open the same solution in VS and attach the debugger to Blend and see what is causing the problem. I haven't tried using this two VS instances. But, you can give it a try.

Comment: Problem is other way around. Blend is OK, VS is what fails

Comment: I got the problem. I am saying try opening 2 instances of VS and attach debugger to one instance of VS and then try to perform the operation and catch what is causing the problem. Please note I haven't tried this

Comment: Just to make everything clear, have you installed SL5 tools for VS?

Comment: I'm going crazy with this now. I uninstalled everything Microsoft Silverlight. And installed just Silverlight 4 stuff. I have one project where I can use those controls. But on other projects (same solution) when I add control - I get this weirdness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it will help someone with similar issues.

My problem was with Silverlight installs on my PC.

I had:
SL4 tools, SDK, etc installed. Also, I had SL5 RC installed when everything was working. Remember, I'm targeting SL4!

So, Silverlight 5 came out, I thought about migrating project but because it is so new - other tooling I use is not there yet. I decided to give it another month or two before migrating. Meanwhile, I decided to cleanup my machine installs.

I uninstalled SL5RC and all this started! I uninstalled ALL SL stuff and installed SL4 latest and greatest and still those issues. I spent about 10 hours trying different things with my resource files and trying to debug this issue. Remember, it is SL4 app!

Today I gave up and just to try got SL5 installed. Boom! It works. I don't know what and how, but installing SL5 did the trick. I really hate mess like this but oh well. Hopefully it will save someone hours.